# Is there a way to use AppleScript to create an iCal alarm that runs AppleScript like you can manually?

Tags: macos, applescript, calendar.app

All I see in iCal's dictionary are display, mail, sound, and open file alarms.

Note:  I know I can save the desired script as an app and create an open file alarm, but that would mean that the alarm would change focus to the app which for me is undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to save the script as an app, simply save it as an AppleScript file and it will run all the same. It won't steal focus if you do it this way. I have tested this and it works.

```
set theFile to "/Users/me/Desktop/myscript.scpt"
tell application "iCal"
   tell calendar "MyCalendar"
      set theDate to (current date) + 1 * minutes
      set theEvent to make new event at end with properties {summary:"it's a script!", description:"run the script", start date:theDate}
      tell theEvent
         make new open file alarm at end with properties {trigger date:theDate, filepath:theFile}
      end tell
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I assumed that would just open the file in the AppleScript Editor.  I'll try it now.

Comment: You're right!  It automatically adjusted to a run script alarm.  Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if this has changed for newer OS versions?  I can't get it to work in Mojave (no alert is ever set)